# Is it possilbe to inherit private constructors with using in cpp >= 11

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, using

Is there a way to inherit private constructors with the using statement?
I tried adding a friend statement, but it did not seem to work.

```
struct B;
struct A
{
private:
    A(int x) {}
    A(int y, double z) {}
    friend struct B;
};
struct B : public A
{
public:
    using A::A;
    //B(int x) : A(x) {}
    //B(int x, int y) : A(x, y) {}
};
void demo()
{
    B b1(5); // does not compile - implicit constructor is not accessible 
    B b2(4, 9.0);
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to do it with using, since if I explicitly create the delegating constructors the friend statement works, so this seams inconsistent:

```
struct B;
struct A
{
private:
    A(int x) {}
    A(int y, double z) {}
    friend struct B;
};
struct B : public A
{
public:
    B(int x) : A(x) {} // OK
    B(int x, int y) : A(x, y) {}
};

void demo()
{
    B b1(5); // OK 
    B b2(4, 9.0);
}
```

Comment: perhaps just wording, but when you inherit, everything is inherited, also private members, it is only a matter of accesing them

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes, of course you are correct. Should have been "possible to inherit and use from a scope outside the inheritor".. ugh.... you see why i didn't :)

Comment: How about "How to access private base class constructor?" you can skip the "is it possible to inherit" part, because all members are inherited. Though, nevermind, the question was clear enough to be answered, I don't want to push you to make it worse

Answer (score 4):

Accessibility of inherited constructors is not affected by the accessibility of the using declaration that introduces them.

> **[namespace.udecl]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/namespace.udecl#19) A synonym created by a using-declaration has the usual
> accessibility for a member-declaration. A using-declarator that names
> a constructor does not create a synonym; instead, **the additional
> constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to
> construct an object of the corresponding base class, and the
> accessibility of the using-declaration is ignored**.

Since you can't access the constructor of `A` in `main`, it isn't accessible to construct a `B` in `main` either (you would be able to use it in order to construct `B`'s and `A`'s inside the scope of `B` though, on account of the friendship). You'll need to spell out some sort of of forwarding c'tor explicitly for outside-the-class access. Since you seem to be after a "catch-all", a fairly simple solution can be

```
template<typename... Args>
B(Args&&... args) : A(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

Comment: "if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class" ... also does not seem to work in a consistent way. Adding a friend statement to the function instantiating B does not work, but it does allow instantiating A with the private constructor. Why?

Comment: @GonenI - Where did you add the extra friend statement? Friendship is not inherited nor transitive. A friend of `B` is not a friend of `A`. Either way, the exact effects of friendship on accessibility is another matter, for another question.

Comment: Ideally you would also apply SFINAE to only let the forwarding ctor of `B` to participate in overload resolution if `A(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is well-formed. Currently it will "catch all" and try to forward to non-existing constructors in `A`, taking precedence over unique ctors in `B` that are not an exact match (e.g. they may have some conversion sequence for at least one ctor argument).

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if there is any way to do it with `using`, since if I explicitly create the delegating constructors the `friend` statement works

No, when `using` the base class constructors, they will keep the original `protected` or `private` access, so you need to implement them in the derived class if you'd like to make them `public`. Making `B` a `friend` doesn't change that. It only allows `B` to access the private members in `A` - both functions and variables.

If you'd like derived classes to be able to use certain `private` member functions, you usually make those member functions `protected` instead.

```
struct A {
protected:
    A(int x) {}
    A(int y, double z) {}
};

struct B : public A {
public:
    B(int x) : A(x) {}
    B(int y, double z) : A(y, z) {}
};
```

With this, you don't need to know about the derived classes when designing `A` and you also keep your `private` member variables in `A` `private`.

Comment: I find that inconsistent, since if I declare the delegating constructors in B explicitly, a friend statement in A does grant access.

Comment: @GonenI It's a matter of taste and depends on the situation. With `friend`, only those specific classes you've granted the access to can use those functions - and they also get _full_ access to your `private` member variables too which is usually not what one wants. With `protected` you can provide functions that anyone who'd like to extend the class can use and still keep the private member variables safe.

Comment: I unfortunately see what appears to be down-voting of one answer while upvoting another one, such that one could argue that some use down-votes to indicate the like another answer better, rather than just omitting to upvote the answers they favour less. But this is pure speculation; anon. non-feedback downvotes are always ungrateful.

Comment: Just speculating, but I believe the OP wants to know why the `using` statement does not provide, or rather invalidates public access to the private members of A, you provide an alternative to it. That said I also don't think your answer is worthy of a DV, an explanation would be in order.

Comment: @anastaciu Yes, I know the mechanics of private and protected, but I did not downvote, I almost never do.

Comment: I am the anonymous downvoter! Sorry about that. I'm not normally but Gonen's comment already mentioned my objection: I felt your first paragraph dismissed the fact that OP had used friend declaration. Yes, that is very odd compared to using a protected specifier, but the question is still interesting in its own right, but you effectively answered it with "don't ask that question".

Comment: @ArthurTacca Would it be clearer if I put the sentence "_When `using` the base class constructors, they will keep the original `protected` or `private` access_" first instead? I swapped places now.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, IMO that's better, since it's the part that directly addresses the OP. My UV is more solid now :).

Comment: @GonenI I also use that tool with parsimony, but I can say I always comment when I do because my goal is to help the OP having a better answer. But voting without comment does not violate SO guidelines so it's legitimate.

Comment: Fortunately @ArthurTacca came forward with a reasoning, which I applaud.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Is the downvote still needed? I polished it a bit more to make it even clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica's answer, which explains that the (inherited) constructors are accessible where the base class constructors would be, here is a very partial solution which will work in some cases:

```
struct A
{
private:
    A(int x) {};
    A(int y, double z) {};
    friend struct B;
};
struct B : public A
{
public:
    friend void demo();
    using A::A;
};

void demo()
{
    B b1(5);
    B b2(4, 9.0);
}

int main() {
    demo();
}
```

Comment: You'll need `friend void demo();` in `struct A`.